# Switch with min - max elements

Tags: javascript

I tried to create a switch function called temp() which should allow the display of a definition once inserted a value.
Currently this doesn't work at all and I can't understand why

```
function temp() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('temp').value);
    var y = document.getElementById('temp1');
    switch (x) {
        case x < 36:
            y = hypothermia;
            break;
        case x > 37:
            y = hyperthermia;
            break;
        case x > 38,5:
            y = pyrexia;
            break;
        default:
            y.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

I also tried to use the "if... else if..." method, but only the first two cases really work, while the rest is just ignored (and I already tried switching ordered).

```
function temp() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('temp').value);
    var y = (document.getElementById('temp1'));
    if (x < 36) y.style.background = "yellow",y.style.color = "blue",y.innerHTML = "hypothermia";
    else if (x < 37) y.style.display = "none";
    else if (x > 37) y.style.background = "yellow",y.style.color = "black",y.innerHTML = "hyperthermia";
    else if (x > 38) y.style.background = "red",y.style.color = "black",y.innerHTML = "pyrexia";
}
```

The HTML page where the function should work is this:

`<table>
<tr>
    <td>TEMPERATURA (°C)</td>
    <td><input type="text" style="font-size:100%" maxlength="4" size="4" id="temp"></td> <td><h3 id="temp1"></h3></td>
    </tr>
</table>`

Comment: Your switch statement isn't going to do anything. You're re-assigning y, not actually editing the element with the id `temp1`.

Comment: @Paul R I'm using just Javascript

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider
I've been learning a bit about javascript only for a couple of weeks, so could you please explain a total beginner like me what do you mean and how can I fix this function? Thanks.

Comment: case x > 38,5:  <---- Did you see the comma?

Comment: 1) in your `if..else if` construction `x > 38` is unreachable (it is already > 37). 2) `parseInt` returns **integer** value. 3) `37` exactly is lost.

Comment: @pro of course: I wanted to express a decimal value. Is it wrong?

Comment: it should be 38.5. May be a typo?

Comment: @pro My mistake. I already corrected the comma. Thanks you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your function to this it will work.

- Changed from `parseInt` to `parseFloat` so your `x > 38.5` will be validate-able
- Swapped validate order, starting with the highest or else it will always break a `x > 37` for value higher than 37 and never hit the `x > 38.5`
- To be able to use expression you need to set the switch to `switch (true)`

```js
function temp() {
  var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('temp').value.replace(',','.'));
  var y = document.getElementById('temp1');
  y.style.display = 'block';
  switch (true) {
    case x > 38.5:                  /*  comma, changed to dot  */
      y.innerHTML = "pyrexia";      /*  assing to inner HTML   */
      break;
    case x > 37:
      y.innerHTML = "normal";
      break;
    case x < 36:
      y.innerHTML = "hypothermia";
      break;
    default:
      y.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', temp);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>TEMPERATURA (°C)</td>
    <td><input type="text" style="font-size:100%" maxlength="4" size="4" id="temp"></td> <td><h3 id="temp1"></h3></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`if else` version

```js
function temp() {
  var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('temp').value.replace(',','.'));
  var y = document.getElementById('temp1');
  y.style.display = 'block';
  if (x > 38.5) {
      y.innerHTML = "pyrexia";
  } else if (x > 37) {
      y.innerHTML = "normal";
  } else if (x < 36) {
      y.innerHTML = "hypothermia";
  } else {
      y.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', temp);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>TEMPERATURA (°C)</td>
    <td><input type="text" style="font-size:100%" maxlength="4" size="4" id="temp"></td> <td><h3 id="temp1"></h3></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @NathanMantovani Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, I did try again, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes, on this page it does work. Sadly, when I paste it in my page it doesn't anymore.

Comment: @NathanMantovani Then my solution work, though you have other issues which I can't help with as I have no access to your page

Comment: Ok, I didn't see your update answer. I tried now and it works. Only, I'rather avoid to insert a button in favor for something more automatic.

Comment: for example, I've tried to call the functin with an "oninput" or "onchange" command

Comment: @NathanMantovani Updated my answer again with such function

Comment: this is missing a condition for when x == 37 or x == 36.  i would try to keep logic and dom updates in separate functions.

Comment: @denov Agree regarding logic/DOM updates ... since OP didn't have `x == 37` etc, I chose to not add it

Comment: @LHSon there was a tiny little, hideous mistake in my function that prevented if from working. Now it does. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @LGSon - see my fiddle in my answer.  this is how i would approach something like this

Comment: @LGSON Before I award you for your simple and practical answer, could you briefly explain me, still being a beginner as I already said, how to "translate" what you did with "if... else" in "switch"?
Also, is there a way to use commas for decimals?

Comment: @NathanMantovani To use commas as dot?, no, but I updated my answer with a `.replace(',','.')` so if someone add a comma it will be changed to a dot before the calculation take place .... I already wrote what I did different to make it work.

Comment: @LGSon You're the best! Is there a way to contact you, should I need more awesome answers from you?

Comment: @NathanMantovani Just drop a comment at a question of yours, starting with `@LGSon`, and I will be notified

Comment: that parseFloat should check for NaN.  it assume that the user enters a number.

Comment: @denov In this case it is taken care of already, as the expression will fail and end up with hiding the target element.

Answer (score 0):

With an if-else if, only the first conditional that evals to true will be called

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Multiple if...else statements can be nested to create an else if clause. Note that there is no elseif (in one word) keyword in JavaScript.

```
if (condition1)
   statement1
else if (condition2)
   statement2
else if (condition3)
   statement3
...
else
   statementN
```

To see how this works, this is how it would look like if the nesting were properly indented:

```
if (condition1)
   statement1
else
   if (condition2)
      statement2
   else
      if (condition3)
...
```

Personally I would try a completely different approach to this - https://jsfiddle.net/denov/9awt48bo/4/

Comment: check out my fiddle.

Comment: It definitely works, but it is too complex a solution for me, at present. I appreciate you for suggesting an elegant solution

Comment: imo, it's less complex as each little bit of functionality is separated in it's own function.  code like this is much easier to debug, test, maintain.  i would encourage you to read and understand it.